# How to make ForeignKey field in a separate table without creating an app

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

This is more of a curiosity question.

Is there a way I could make a ForeignKey field with a table below?

I know I could separate the models into separate app but apart froom creating seperate models file.

```
from account.models import User

class Department(models.Model):
    **department_head = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)**
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Employee(User):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, max_length=200)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I expect to make a foreignkey relationship bw department and employee but don't want to create a seperate file or app.